# Wrong result when converting time to UTC

Tags: php, timezone, utc

I am wrote a script which converts my timezone to gmt and vice versa perfectly.......but when i try to check the same function for DST following timzones i am getting wrong result.
here is my function goes............

```
function ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time,$currentTimezone,$timezoneRequired)
{

 $current_zone = new DateTimeZone($currentTimezone);
// print_r($current_zone);
 //$gmt = new DateTimeZone('GMT');

 $date = new DateTime($time, $current_zone);
//var_dump($date);
 //$date->setTimezone($gmt);
 $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezoneRequired));

 return  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Convert it back to Original timezone
 //$date->setTimezone($current_zone);
 //return  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

$time='2011-03-29 9:53:00';

echo  "Current Date/Time is = ".
      ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time,'Asia/Kolkata','UTC');
```

this function works fine for 'Asia/Kolkata' but when i try with  America/New_York timezone. i am getting wrong result.......
please check the code and help me to fix the error.

Comment: Why did you deface your question?

Answer (score 2):

The result is "Current Date/Time is = 2011-03-29 13:23:00" with "America/New_York timezone", and it seems that it's correct.

What you might think weird is that New York is GMT-5 and it should be "2011-03-29 14:23:00".

However, DST(Daylight Saving Time) started on 2011/3/13 and will ends on 2011/11/6.
Thus, during DST period, it would be the same as GMT-4.

Check New York time with DST:
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=179

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question (and code) could be related with **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471448/how-to-make-datetime-class-to-work-with-dst-and-without-dst-in-php)**. So your solution is there. Btw, have you found what's wrong about converting time to UTC from different timezones? You don't need to use last parameter of function (boolean true/false) then, because UTC doesn't observe daylight saving time so basically you will get same time as function's result, with or without DST included in function.